# javascript function to return object returns [object Object]

Tags: javascript

The intended output of my function is `{"name": "bob", "number": 1}`, but it returns `[object Object]`. How can I achieve the desired output?

```
function myfunc() {
   return {"name": "bob", "number": 1};
}
myfunc();
```

Comment: How do you know what the function returns? Are you using a console? Are you `alert()`ing the result?

Comment: I'm using freecodecamp's coding console

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Haha this seems to be a simple misunderstanding. You are returning the object, but the `toString()` method for an object is `[object Object]` and it's being implicitly called by the freecodecamp console.

[Object.prototype.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)

```
var o = {}; // o is an Object
o.toString(); // returns [object Object]
```

You can easily verify you actually are returning an object using your own code:

```js
function myfunc() {
   return {"name": "bob", "number": 1};
}

var myobj = myfunc();
console.log(myobj.name, myobj.number); // logs "bob 1"
```

Comment: How would you call the object when you don't know the key values? I.e I want to console.log the contents of the object since I don't know what it contains

Comment: @DCoderT you can use `Object.entries()`. Check out the example here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Answer (score 4):

If you try `console.log(ob.name)` it should display `bob`

`{}` in JS is a shorthand for an object. You can convert your object to string using the `toString()` method.